# How to commit/accept consuming message before performing a code

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, masstransit

```
    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<ISomeCommand> context)
{
    context.Commit(); 
    // accepted incoming message
    // the message was deleted from queue
    // and it will not be redelivered 

    CallOperationWhichHasARiskBeRetried();
    // Called operation successfully

    context.Publish<IHighRiskJobDone>(new { });
}

public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<ISomeCommand> context)
{
    context.Commit();
    // accepted incoming message
    // the message was deleted from queue
    // and it will not be redelivered 

    CallOperationWhichHasARiskBeRetried();
    // thrown exception
    // should publish Fault<> event
}
```

How can I mark the consuming message as consumed, so that the following code will not be re-delivered in any case if the consumer suddenly disconnects from the network,

I searched in the masstransit documentation, but I didn't find it.

Comment: Format any code or references in the questions itself, do not post pictures through external links.

Comment: There is no manual ack for mass transit - run the processing code in a background thread/task to allow the `Consume` method to immediately return (to ack the message).